# How to handle OPTIONS requests with django-rest-api

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

instead of a **post request**, an **option request** reaches django's rest api and is apparently rejected with

`"OPTIONS /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 425`

How do I handle this option request in the same way like the original post request? What do I have to change or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **OPTIONS** request, responds with the Schema of the DRF endpoint. You need to provide the correct **Authentication** with it.
Imho it's not a **POST** alternative.

I recommend **Postman** to try it out.